# DataFrame append() method does not append data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3

I created a method that suppose to append many dataframes (df) into one(base_df) in a for loop. It doesn't bring any errors,just base_df stays empty. df dataframe has data. Please help. Thank you.

````
#concatenate all files into one dataframe.
def concatenate_all_in_one( bucket, prefix):

    response = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    content_list = response['Contents']
    base_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for item in content_list:
        try:  
            df = get_df_by_bucket_and_key(bucket, item['Key']) #this works fine
            print("this is df name of the file", item['Key'] )
            print("this is df info", df.head())
            base_df = base_df.append(df,ignore_index = True )
        except Exception as e :
            print(e)
            print("Did not append", item['Key'])

    print("This is base_df info", base_df.info())       
    return base_df ```
````

Comment: How do you know *base_df* is empty? Please show print output of *df* and *base_df*.

Comment: Hello @Parfait, I could not reproduce this issue. When I run test on lambda I got a message asking me if I want to work local or remote. I clicked remote and my lambda ran just fine, and dataframes got appended into one. The issue is over, but I don't know how and what happened. Thank you for contribution!